# How to make GNU/Linux more robust in case of frequent power loss

Tags: linux, mount, data-integrity

When having a system (hardware), that has no protection against sudden power loss (zero power at all), what is the best way to keep the damage that may occur to a running GNU/Linux as low as possible?

What I've thought about so far:

- Chosing the right **file system**, maybe ext4 because of journaling, but I don't know if this is the best choice, especially on a sd card.
- Chosing the right **mount options**, for example writing to disk instantly instead of caching it in the ram (I don't know how to do this)
- Keeping **system services** to a bare minimum, especially those with much disk access, maybe **disable logging**
- Mount `/tmp` as **tmpfs**

Are those measures a good thing to do and/or do you know how to further minimise the probability of breakage in case of power loss. (I'm talking only of what to do in software, not hardware)

**EDIT:**
Possible mount options would be `sync` and `dirsync`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it a Pi?

Comment: @nitro2k01 yes, it's a Pi!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with robust system you will lose data. It's only the question of time. So first thing you should do is to setup [backup software](https://wiki.debian.org/BackupAndRecovery).

When you backup is done you can start tuning. There is a good file system, specially designed for flash memory - F2FS. Use it for your data (/home, /media, etc.). You can also setup [read-only root](https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot) partition. ext2 or ext3/ext4 without a journal is a good choice for /.

As you mentioned in your question, tmpfs is a good choice for /tmp and any other places like /var/run, /var/lock etc.

Sync, dirsync will impact performance and life of your SD card. You can use noatime instead and/or [tune /proc/sys/vm](http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm) for increasing disk flushing frequency.

Disabling unused services and especially logging will also reduce disk writes. [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) will help you to identify them.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually think about separating the written data to a separate partition but it really makes sense. Also mounting the root readonly should save nearly all problems because the system stays intact and the application that's running only changes a few text files.